# How to Upload videos to my channel on you tube from android?

Tags: youtube-api

Want to upload videos to my channel on youtube directly from **android** and **iOS** using **youtube API v3**.

I know "client login" of Youtube API v2 is now deprecated and cannot use any more now, but is there any method in V3 API that we can use now to achieve the video upload to my channel on youtube without user interaction or without user prompt to ask username or password?

Comment: Welcome to the website, and thank you for the question. After submitting the question, please make sure that the formatting looks fine.

Comment: What have you tried so far with v3? What you want is not documented in https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/uploading_a_video?hl=en? Could you specify with a little more details what you tried and what fails. Welcome to SO, recommended reading: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I want to upload videos to fix YouTube account without user interaction from my android app.<br>

Comment: I want to upload videos to fix YouTube account without user interaction using v3 from my android app.   I tried to get Access token as described in Google YouTube Doc in https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp . But ,How do i use this Access token to upload YouTube video from my android code.      I found android code in which clientAuthLogin get from googleaccount credential object.How can i utilize access token in android app to upload video ?

Answer (score 0):

Letting other people upload random videos to your channel is not recommended. That's why OAuth2 only lets them to upload to their own channel. You can use YouTube Direct Lite for people to upload to their channel, but you can still collect those videos into your playlist.

https://code.google.com/p/youtube-direct-lite/

https://github.com/youtube/yt-direct-lite-iOS

https://github.com/youtube/yt-direct-lite-android

Comment: When i run yt-direct-lite-android it is constantly showing "Connection to play services failed toast " and not even choosing account. Is it possible to make user upload on my channel by any other way and how can i add a video to my play list ? i could not find that part in yt-direct-lite-android ?