# Upload video on a specific channel of youtube in Android

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api

I am working with youtube API and want to upload the video on youtube on my own channel. I am using the Youtube intents but this intent open the youtube application and the user logged in on that application can upload on his/her own account's channel. I want that the video is uploaded on my own channel. I have seen these questions on SO but still unclear.

[Is it possible to upload videos on specific channel through youtube API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18412492/is-it-possible-to-upload-videos-on-specific-channel-through-youtube-api)

[How to Upload videos to my channel on you tube from android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30591404/how-to-upload-videos-to-my-channel-on-you-tube-from-android)

Can I do this or not using Youtube API?

Comment: did you find a way to upload to your own channel ?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30591404/how-to-upload-videos-to-my-channel-on-you-tube-from-android) you provided, you need [OAuth2](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication) to upload videos in your own channel. Your application directs the user to Google's authorization server. The link to that page specifies the `scope` of access that your application is requesting for the user's account. The `scope` specifies the resources that your application can retrieve, insert, update, or delete when acting as the authenticated user.

These links might also help: [Displaying Youtube Videos From Specific Channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25607356/displaying-youtube-videos-from-specific-channel) and [Youtube API : Upload videos to a specific channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14951065/youtube-api-upload-videos-to-a-specific-channel)

Comment: can you provide any working example? i want all the users upload on my channel . currenty i can only make them upload on there channel and get video link.